# ANSIBLE - Json_Query - Filter result

Tags: ansible, json-query

Inside my ansible playbook, I' m trying to filter a json result but for now, it doesn't work.

**1/ Playbook**
*Below My ansible playbook to query and filter the result:*

---

```
tasks:
    - name: "Query Attributes" 
          ...
          ...
      register: query_result

    - name: Display Result
      debug: 
        var: query_result  

    - name: Display Filtered Result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query_result.current| json_query('[].context.attributes[?name==`prod`].name') }}"
```

Maybe an issue inside my json_query filter ?
Any idea ?

---

**2/ Query_result output before filtering**

```
TASK [Display Result] ***************************************************
"query_result": {
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                    }, 
                    "changed": false, 
                    "current": [
                        {
                            "context": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "name": "prod", 
                                    "uid": "11756"
                                }
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
....
                                }
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "context": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "name": "dev", 
                                    "uid": "14424"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ], 
                    "failed": false
                }
            }

*****************************
```

**3/ Filtered result is empty**
Unfortunately my result is empty.

```
    TASK [Display Filtered Result] **********************************************************    
{    
                "msg": []    
            }
```

Thank you
Ju

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, single and double quotes matter in [jmespath expressions specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html). Your literal string for the search needs to be single quoted.

Second, your filter will not match. You either have to move your filter at a higher level in the the stream processing or to pipe your expression.

Below are some examples that illustrate the above recommendations and lead to the same result

```
---
- name: Filter with jmespath
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    query_result: {
      "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
      },
      "changed": false,
      "current": [
         {
           "context": {
             "attributes": {
               "name": "prod",
               "uid": "11756"
             }
           }
         },
         {
           "context": {
             "attributes": {
               "name": "dev",
               "uid": "14424"
             }
           }
         }
      ],
      "failed": false
    }

  tasks:

    - name: Display original result
      debug: var=query_result

    - name: Display Filtered Result - One expression - one liner
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query_result.current | json_query(\"[?context.attributes.name=='prod'].context.attributes.name[]\") }}"

    - name: Display Filtered Result - One expression - Query in block var
      vars:
        query: >-
          [?context.attributes.name=='prod'].context.attributes.name[]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query_result.current | json_query(query) }}"

    - name: Display Filtered Result - Pipe expressions - Query in block var
      vars:
        query: >-
          [].context.attributes[] | [?name=='prod'].name[]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query_result.current | json_query(query) }}"
```

For your next question, please read the help section and consider providing a [full MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question (as I just did in this answer).